# Twitter feeds v 1.1 and return json object for each tweet

Tags: java, javascript, json, twitter

I am trying to integrate twitter feeds in my website. I want each tweet obtained from a user as a seperate json object so tat i can customise the look and feel of each object.
Can anyone help me with this ?

I have generated the OAUTH token.How do i use it in my code? I dont want to use PHP. Is there any other way using java or javascript?

I am using this link to access my twitter feeds:
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=bindyareddy&since_id=24012619984051000&max_id=250126199840518145&result_type=mixed&count=4

I am getting JSON response like :

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Bad Authentication data",
            "code": 215
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Try using the library [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply i am using twitter4j and i am facing the exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/crypto/Mac .I am using maven for building. I have added the dependency for twitter4j as well. any idea about this?

Comment: add jce-jdk13-119.jar , you can download it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjcejdk13119jar.htm)

Comment: not working :( Added the dependency :<dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcprov-jdk13</artifactId>
      <version>132</version>
    </dependency>